# jsFiddle /echo/html not working with jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/YcK5X/
I'm wondering why this AJAX request doesn't return anything.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/echo/html',
    data: 'Echo!',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#ajax').html(data);
    },
    dataType: 'text/html'
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The data you want echo:ed must be supplied in a POST parameter named html:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/echo/html/',
  data: {
    'html': 'Echo!'
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $('#ajax').html(data);
  },
  dataType: 'text/html'
});
```

Comment: You must have already noticed this because you corrected it, but `url: '/echo/html'` had to be changed to `url: '/echo/html/'`

Comment: Thanks! I've already figured out that `data: { html: 'Echo!' }`, and it still didn't work, but with thirtydot's slip, it's now working! Also, a much shorter way: `$('#ajax').load('/echo/html/', { html: 'Hello!' });`

Comment: dataType: 'html' if using Jquery 1.5 or higher

Comment: And, of course, if a new reader is still trying to make this example work, you must include the script tags to the jquery library at the top of the html pane: (e.g. <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>).  ALSO NOTE thirtydot and frictionlesspulley's necessary mods above.