# JQuery return code

Tags: ajax, jquery

Got a problem with jquery. I cant get a .xml file from the server, using the ajax function in jquery. I tried to call an alert upon succes and upon error, but nothing triggers. I did it this way:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Levels.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    error: function(){

        alert("Ajax failed!");

    },
    success: function(xml){
              alert(xml);

            }
    });
```

That did not work.
Edit: I have this code in my xml file:

```
<?xmlversion="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Level id="TestLevel" theme="woods">
       <Wall>
    <Row>111111111111111111111</Row>
    <Row>100000000000000000001</Row>
    <Row>100000000000000000001</Row>
    <Row>100000000000000000001</Row>
    <Row>100000000000000000001</Row>
    <Row>100000000000000000001</Row>
    <Row>100000000000000000001</Row>
    <Row>100000000000000000001</Row>
    <Row>100000000000000000001</Row>
    <Row>100000000000000000001</Row>
    <Row>100000000000000000001</Row>
    <Row>111111111111111111111</Row>
    </Wall>
     </Level>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're calling the function in the first place? Any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Is the server seeing the request? Are you sure that code is even being executed at all?

Comment: No error messages. And yes it is called

Comment: Have you debugged it with Firebug (firefox) or with chrome? What is the reply of the request?

Comment: I debugged it with the javascriptconsol in chrome and there was no errors.

Comment: Does your xml file is placed within the same level as your javascript file ?

Comment: Does your server serve XML files with the proper MIME type (text/xml)?

Comment: Im not exactly sure about the mime type...

Comment: my xml file is in the same directory as my .js file

Comment: Your syntax seems fine.  Sure you included jQuery correctly?  See this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528392/jsfiddle-echo-html-not-working-with-jquery

Comment: I included JQuery via this line in my html file: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: And i include JQuery before my.js script

Comment: I dont know why, but it worked when i got home from school. But it does not give me any data?? Just gives me a undefined variable.

Comment: I made a edit to show you what i got in the xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaming the XML File to something else like `"sites.xml"` fixes this on my server.

Appears that "levels" is somehow related to the xml request by ajax.

cheers

PrimuS