# Using the jsfiddle echo api with jquery

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

I am trying to use the **[echo api in jsfiddle](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html)** to simulate an AJAX request.

The code I am using is pretty simple (**[live version](http://jsfiddle.net/kjjt5/1/)**):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/html/',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        html: '<p>Hello, it\'s me</p>'
    },
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(jqXHR);
        $('body').append(data);
    }
});​
```

As far as I can tell this should be working in theory, yet in real life I get a successfull response with no data. I also found **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528392/jsfiddle-echo-html-not-working-with-jquery)**, but I am doing exactly what is stated there, so I am a little confused. Am I doing something wrong? Has something with the echo api changed? Am I missing something substantial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `method` instead of `type`, so the request is sent as a `GET` and not a `POST`:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

[Updated Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/kjjt5/2/).

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/html/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        html: '<p>Hello, it\'s me</p>'
    },
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(jqXHR);
        $('body').append(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ha, it's one of those typos where you just stare and stare and stare at the code and it refuses to look wrong :)